# How to transform plane equation

Tags: plane-geometry

I have the following mapping from R3 -> R3:

```
Vector3 f(Vector3 v) {
  // Only points with |x| < z and |y| < z and 0 < z <= SomeConstant are of interest
  assert(abs(v.x) <= v.z);
  assert(abs(v.y) <= v.z);
  assert(v.z > 0);
  assert(v.z <= SomeConstant);
  Vector3 res;
  res.x = v.x / v.z;
  res.y = v.y / v.z;
  res.z = v.z / SomeConstant;
  return res;
}
```

under this mapping, points that lie on a plane will also still lie on a plane afterwards.

Now, if I have a plane equation in the form `a*x + b*y + c*z - d = 0`, how can I transform the parameters `P = [a, b, c, d]` so that I'm getting a plane `P' = [a', b', c', d']` such that all points on the original plane `P` will lie on plane `P'` after being transformed by the above function?

Comment: Are you sure about the condition you’ve stated in “Under the mapping…” Seems suspect to me. For one thing, it is undefined with $z=0,$ so it is not a map $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3.$

Comment: yeah you're right. I'm only dealing with points that have SomeConstant > z > 0. Will add that to the question

Comment: I still don’t think it sends coplanar points to coplanar points.

Comment: It does, since straight lines are preserved. It does not preserve angles though

Comment: $(1,1,1),(1,2,3),(1,3,5)$ are colinear, are $(1,1,1/C),(1/3,2/3,3/C)$ and $(1/5,3/5,5/C)$ colinear, for any $C?$ No.